# Is it possible to get permutations for a String that has repeated characters?

Tags: flutter, dart, permutation

I am currently using the trotter dart package on flutter, however it is unable to generate all permutations of strings with repeated numbers.

It works fine with 1234, but not with 2344.

Comment: generate all the permutations for [0,1,2,3] array and use them as indices to any other list

Comment: But then you have duplicate permutations, because different indices have same numbers.

Comment: @TThoEinthausend OP wants those dups - at least this is what i understood from him...

Answer (score 5):

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of `trotter`. Thanks for your interest in my library!)

When dealing with a moderate number of items, we can simply create a mapping from a regular sequence of permutations of indices to respective items in an arbitrary list.

In this case, the arbitrary list contains the items in the string `'2344'`, so we could generate the permutations of these items as follows. (Notice, however, with indistinguishable items, the permutations are not unique. We could get rid of non unique items by converting to a `Set`, though.)

```dart
import 'package:trotter/trotter.dart';

main() {
  final items = characters('2344'),
      indices = List<int>.generate(items.length, (i) => i),
      permsOfItems = indices
          .permutations()
          .iterable
          .map((perm) => perm.map((index) => items[index]).join());

  print('All permutations (including non unique):');
  for (final perm in permsOfItems) {
    print(perm);
  }

  print('\nOnly unique:');
  for (final perm in permsOfItems.toSet()) {
    print(perm);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
All permutations (including non unique):
2344
2344
2434
4234
4243
2443
2443
2434
4234
4243
4423
4423
4432
4432
4342
4324
3424
3442
3442
4342
4324
3424
3244
3244

Only unique:
2344
2434
4234
4243
2443
4423
4432
4342
4324
3424
3442
3244
```