# How do I get all combinations of a number with repeated digits?

Tags: flutter, dart, combinations, permutation

I am able to use the dart trotter package to get combinations of numbers that do not have digits that repeat, instance: 1234.

However, when I try to do that for a number like 1112, it says items are not unique.

What I am trying to achieve is:
1112, 
1121,
1211,
2111

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: please provide your code to who can run it to see the error you mentioned.

Comment: It looks as though you're after *permutations* rather than combinations... This is a very similar question to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831836/is-it-possible-to-get-permutations-for-a-string-that-has-repeated-characters/59433699#59433699).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are more interested in the case where *order is important* (otherwise 1112 and 1121, for example, would be considered equivalent - in other words, *permutations* rather than *combinations*.).

There are several ways of achieving what you want using trotter.

Assuming you have already set up the dependency in `pubspec.yaml`...

```
dependencies:
  trotter: ^1.1.1
```

... and imported the library...

```dart
import 'package:trotter/trotter.dart';
```

you could, for example:

1. create items '1112'
2. permute indices 0-3
3. map the index permutations to arrangements of items
4. discard "extra" copies of generated items (for example, by taking a set of arrangements)

```dart
final items = '1112',
    indices = [0, 1, 2, 3],
    desired = {
      ...indices
        .permutations(4)()
        .map((permutation) => 
          permutation.map((index) => 
            items[index]).join())
    };

print(desired);
```

```
{1112, 1121, 1211, 2111}
```

Alternatively, you could permute three distinct "1" items and a "2" item, and then process and remove duplicates.

```dart
final desired = {
  for (final permutation in ['1a', '1b', '1c', '2'].permutations(4)())
    permutation.join().replaceAll(RegExp('[^12]'), '')
};

print(desired);
```

```
{1112, 1121, 1211, 2111}
```